# SAS DATA STEP: subset multiple rows without using first/last

Tags: sql, oracle, sas, subset

I'm trying to pull back all MAX instances given subset data....first.id or last.id doesn't work because I want to keep several rows of the same transaction. For example:

[TableView_of_Data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qtCbl.jpg)

In this example I want the highlighted rows as output. My data has several FORMs, QUARTERs, and CUST_ID I'd like to programmatically have SAS pull back latest based on FORM, QUARTER, CUST_ID

Last.DB_ID only brings back 1 row. I need all rows of the same DB_ID.

also this failed to do anything:

```
data work.want;
set work.have;
by FORM Quarter Cust_ID DB_ID ;
if Max(DB_ID) then output;
run;
```

Comment: You have tagged this with Oracle and SQL.  Why?  Is the data starting in a database?

Comment: Yes, data is housed in Oracle and I can use SQL via SAS to query from DW.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to do two passes through your data: one to determine what the max value is for that ID, and one to find the rows that have that maximum value.

Doing this in the data step requires a DoW loop, which runs one data step iteration per cust_id value but two passes through the dataset.

```
data want;
  do _n_ = 1 by 1 until (last.cust_id);
    set have;
    by form quarter cust_id;
    if last.cust_id then max_db_value=db_id;
  end;
  do _n_ = 1 by 1 until (last.cust_id);
    set have;
    by form quarter cust_id;
    if db_id = max_db_Value then output;
  end;
run;
```

That works if DB_ID is sorted as it is in your example.  If it's not sorted, you can compare the currently stored max_db_value to the current db_id and assign the new value from db_id to it if it's higher, something like

```
max_db_value = max(db_id, max_db_value);
```

instead of assigning it when `last.cust_id` is true.